# How to convert a Noun Phrase into a keyword

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp, text-analysis

I'm working on a keyword extraction task in which the candidate keywords are the noun phrases that I obtain after applying part of speech tagging (pos) and chunking. However I polish the noun phrase a little bit more. That is, I remove the stop words from their beginning (or their end). I also need to apply stemming. However I'm not sure how to apply stemming on multiple-word phrases. does it make sense to apply stemming on multiple-word phrases at all or I should leave them as is? apart from stop word removal and possible stemming, is there anything else that I can do?

Comment: I haven't got time to clean up my code but you can try: https://github.com/alvations/Terminator and https://goo.gl/r2n1PL

Comment: Is the code implementation of the paper?

Comment: Yes it is but only the terminology part =)